# Integrate a function with respect to a different variable?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm suppose to integrate this function,$$\int\left(e^{3t}-\frac{3}{t}\right)dx$$
I took the antiderivative and got the incorrect answer, the correct one being:

$$\left(e^{3t}-\frac{3}{t}\right)x$$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You were supposed to treat that entire integrand as if it were a constant.

Comment: You can consider other variables as constant.

Comment: If I pull out the constant, where does x come in to play? Shouldn't it have just been the same function?

Comment: $\int 1 dx = x$

Comment: I'm an idiot... Righto, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, try to solve $$\int 1\,dx \text{.}$$

Then solve $$\int a\,dx \text{,}$$
which is easy since it's just another way of writing $$a\int 1\,dx\text{.}$$

Now replace $a$ by your integrand $e^{3t} - \frac{3}{t}$. You may do that because it's value doesn't depend on $x$, so for the purpose of integrating over $x$, it's just a plain old constant.