# (Probably a Silly Question) Definite Integral With Respect to Independent Variable?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I was trying to understand how to evaluate and indefinite integral of a function with respect to a independent variable and after reading through this [Integrate a function with respect to a different variable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596368/integrate-a-function-with-respect-to-a-different-variable), I learned that we can treat all terms independent of the variable we are integrating with respect to as constants.

Then I just thought to myself, "huh that's interesting, I wonder how this changes when it's a definite integral?". And I found this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2576079/taking-the-derivative-of-a-definite-integral-with-respect-to-a-different-variabl) but only got confused by trying to understand what they we're talking about. Now I just think this is a silly question because there isn't much out there online about it, but I was curious if someone could explain to me why it was a silly question? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by how it changes when it is a definite integral? Remember that definite integrals can be seen as indefinite integrals, evaluated at 2 points and substracted one from the other.